# Command to sort 3 letters month in AIX

Tags: sorting

Have a file containing values :
Sep 17 11:07 2016
Jan 03 20:33 2018
Apr 14 11:53 2015
Dec 28 07:28 2017
Aug 10 11:55 2011
Dec 25 17:53 2017

Have sort -M option in other flavors of UNIX OS. But no luck in AIX.
Please help in sorting 3 letter month. Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Used `sed` to convert your file: `sed 's/^Jan /01 /; ... s/^Nov /11 /; s/^Dec/12 /' fromfile >tofile`

Comment: it helped!:) Thanks a lot Lorinczy.